# Median of a distribution given its density

Tags: statistics

How can I find the median of this distribution?

$f(u)∝ e^{(−5u^2 + 10u)}$

I'm not sure if I have to use an absolute loss function or something much simpler. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the underlying domain of $u$-values the "density" $f(u)$ applies to.  Is it all real numbers?  Only the nonnegative real numbers?  Only integers??

Comment: What is the question? *By definition*, one must solve for $m$ the identity  $$\int_{-\infty}^me^{-5u^2+10u}du=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5u^2+10u}du.$$ Or, one can note that the PDF is symmetric with respect to $2$, since $$f(u)=f(4-u),$$ hence $$m=2.$$